# Class Declaration causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, calendar, nullpointerexception, proguard

My program crashes due to a null pointer exception.

Snip of Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.my.GRTRecTimeSortComparator.compare(SourceFile:15)
```

That's well and good.  But my problem is that  line 15 is the class declaration:

```
15 public class GRTRecTimeSortComparator   implements Comparator<GRTRecord> {
16    @Override
17    public int compare(GRTRecord rec1, GRTRecord rec2) {
18      
19      int returnVal=rec1.getRecordCalendar().compareTo(rec2.getRecordCalendar());
20        return returnVal;
21    }
22}
```

It's calling out the Compare function, but I don't see an issue with that either.  Every record has a Unique Calendar assigned to it as well.

Any ideas? What have I done wrong here?

Edit: in response to queries:

No, there is nothing strange about the class itself, other than the fact I wrote it.

I AM using Proguard.  Maybe the Obfuscation is replacing things incorrectly?

I'm writing up tests for the records right now.  They SHOULDN'T be `null`, nor should the `Calendars`;  I use them immediately before, and get good results.

Maybe I'm just passing the `ArrayList` incorrectly.

EDIT 2:

Logging lines inserted into the class never get run.
No matter what I add or do to the class, the null pointer always resolves to the class declaration line.

Removed Proguard Obfuscation, and still no dice.

I'm REALLY frustrated.

Edit 3:

For Future Users:

Proguard ruins your stack trace.  That was the cause of the Above.  Remove proguard if you run into issues.

The CAUSE was actually a corrupted record in the dataset.

Comment: Most likely, the source you're reading from is out of sync with the stack-trace inside your compiled code.  Try building from clean, and then re-run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the debug information is just out of sync. Put logging into your `compare` method. I would log (in order):

- `rec1`
- `rec2`
- `rec1.getRecordCalendar()`
- `rec2.getRecordCalendar()`

If this isn't the problem, is there anything "odd" about the class in any other way? For example:

- Are you using Hibernate or something similar which may be creating proxies for you?
- Is this an inner class?

Comment: No Hibernate.  I do not believe there is anything out of the normal, other than using Proguard.  This is all within a Netbeans Paltform Application, occuring in one of the SwingWorkers.

Comment: @Sheriff: And have you put in the logging I suggested? I wouldn't be *at all* surprised if Proguard was messing with the stack traces though.

Comment: I put in the logging.  It was never run, though.  I disabled Proguard, and that shifts the Stack trace failure to the `Compare` function, as one would expect.  Re-enabling logging to see what happens now.

Comment: Logging worked this time.  They all have values assigned to them.  Since the CompareTo function is an innate Calendar function, I'd assume it should work.  But I'll play with it some more.

Comment: @Sheriff: Is the exception still being thrown, even after the logging?

Comment: Yes it is.  Logging appears to work, but the exception is thrown partway through the file.  It sorts, but the exception is really weird.  If I log the value of `rec1`, it throws the exception there.  It does NOT with `rec2`.  If I do not log `rec1`, it throws the exception at the actual `compareTo` line.

Comment: @Sheriff: How are you logging `rec1`, exactly? (Can you post the line of code?)

Comment: outStream.print(rec2.getRecordCalendar().getTime().toString() + "\r\n");
outStream.print(rec1.getRecordCalendar().getTime().toString() + "\r\n");
outStream.flush();

Comment: I found it Jon.  I'm sorry for the lengthy back and forth.  It turns out the dataset that I have been given possesses a corrupted Record, about 200 records in.  That's the whole problem.

Comment: @Sheriff: Well that's going to go bang if `rec1` is null, isn't it? I was suggesting you *just* used `outStream.print("rec1 = " + rec1)`.

Comment: @Sheriff: So was `rec1` null in that case, as suspected?

Comment: It was that rec1 contained a mangled `long`;  in translation to my program That became a `null`.  I should have been more thorough in my logging, and used the hash.  Thank you, Jon.

Answer (score 1):

At times like these, its good to set your debugger to break on error.  You will know exactly where your NPE is.

Comment: I guess this is time for me to learn how to really use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try checking for a null rec1 and rec2 for completeness

Comment: None are null.  The `ArrayList` contains 127996 records, all with good `Calendar` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing comparator interface then you can use only `compare()` method but you are trying to access `compareTo()` method of comparable which you didn't implement.
In your program:

The comparing value is returned in the form of reference form which could not be return to a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard tries to preserve debugging information as much as possible, but that is not always technically possible. For instance, if the method getRecordCalendar gets inlined, any exceptions that the method throws are now thrown from the invocation site.